# split username & password from URL in 3.8+ (splituser is deprecated, no alternative)

Tags: python-3.x, url

trying to filter out the user-password from a URL.

(I could've split it manually by the last '@' sign, but I'd rather use a parser)

Python gives a deprecation warning but `urlparse()` doesn't handle user/password.

Should I just trust the last-@-sign, or is there a new version of split-user?

```
Python 3.8.2 (default, Jul 16 2020, 14:00:26) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
>>> url="http://usr:pswd@www.site.com/path&var=val"
>>> import urllib.parse

>>> urllib.parse.splituser(url)
<stdin>:1: DeprecationWarning: urllib.parse.splituser() is deprecated as of 3.8, use urllib.parse.urlparse() instead
('http://usr:pswd', 'www.site.com/path&var=val')

>>> urllib.parse.urlparse(url)
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='usr:pswd@www.site.com', path='/path&var=val', params='', query='', fragment='') 

#neigher with allow_fragments:

>>> urllib.parse.urlparse(url,allow_fragments=True)
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='us:passw@ktovet.com', path='/all', params='', query='var=val', fragment='')
```

(Edit: the repr() output is partial & misleading; see my answer.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's all there, clear and accessible.

What went wrong:  The repr() here is misleading, showing only few properties / values (why? it's another question).

The result is available with explicit property get:

```
>>> url = 'http://usr:pswd@www.sharat.uk:8082/nativ/page?vari=valu'
>>> p = urllib.parse.urlparse(url)

>>> p.port
8082
>>> p.hostname
'www.sharat.uk'
>>> p.password
'pswd'
>>> p.username
'usr'
>>> p.path
'/nativ/page'
>>> p.query
'vari=valu'
>>> p.scheme
'http'
```

Or as a one-liner (I just needed the domain):

```
>>> urllib.parse.urlparse('http://usr:pswd@www.sharat.uk:8082/nativ/page?vari=valu').hostname
www.shahart.uk
```

Comment: Except that it isn't all there. `splituser()[1]` gave you a `host[:port]` string (ie netloc w/o credentials). now you manually need to build this string if you want it...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source code for `splituser`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.6/Lib/urllib/parse.py#L1038), looks like they simply use [`str.rpartition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition):

```py
def splituser(host):
    warnings.warn("urllib.parse.splituser() is deprecated as of 3.8, "
                  "use urllib.parse.urlparse() instead",
                  DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
    return _splituser(host)


def _splituser(host):
    """splituser('user[:passwd]@host[:port]') --> 'user[:passwd]', 'host[:port]'."""
    user, delim, host = host.rpartition('@')
    return (user if delim else None), host
```

which yes, relies on the last occurrence of `@`.

EDIT: `urlparse` still has all these fields, see Berry's answer